# JS function works on console, but not in code

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I run $('#slides').superslides() in my console my function works properly, however when I run it in a separate JS file it displays nothing.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#slides').superslides();

});
```

File is correctly referenced in script

```
 <html lang="en" dir="ltr">
   <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <title>Brandon Bracho</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/superslides.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
     <div id="slides">
       <div class="slides-container">
         <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>



     <script src="Javascript/jquery.superslides.min.js"</script>
     <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
     <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
     <script src="Javascript/script.js"</script>
   </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Did you check the browser's console for errors?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's relevant, but see concluding the <script> tag in `<script src =" Javascript/jquery.superslides.min.js"</script>` and `<script src="Javascript/script.js" </script> `in both is missing `>` after the `src` attribute

Comment: Yup, no errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should not work, u have typo on your script

```html
<script src="Javascript/jquery.superslides.min.js"</script>
```

you are not closing the start tag, please close it:

```html
<script src="Javascript/jquery.superslides.min.js"></script>
```

and also your reference to your script `Javascript/script.js` maybe invalid as it is mean an absolute path, please check it on the browser console (check if it is loaded)

Comment: great . nice to hear that, don't forget to set it as working solution. thanks